# How to update a model with an array property in sailsjs waterline

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have this model with friends property as a type of array.

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    id : {
        type: 'integer',
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    username : {
      type : 'string',
      required : true,
      unique : true
    },
    email : 'string',
    firstname : 'string',
    lastname : 'string',
    password : 'string',
    friends : 'array'
  },
   beforeCreate: function(values, next) {
    bcrypt.hash(values.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      values.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  }
};
```

This is my route method.

```
addFriend : function (req, res) {
    User.findOne({username : req.session.user.username}).exec(function (err, user) {
        if(!user.friends)user.friends = [];
        user.friends.push(req.param('friend'));
        user.save(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
}
```

I've used User.update(criteria, data) to update the model, but I can't even update the model at all using .save(), even doing this ...

```
addFriend : function (req, res) {
    User.findOne({username : req.session.user.username}).exec(function (err, user) {
        user.firstname = 'Nate';
        user.save(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
}
```

Is there any other way to save without doing Model.update, or how can I push to an array using that method. I've looked everywhere why I can't solve this, and I've used many orm's in node as well as all the waterline docs show using the save on a model after finding.

This is the error I get on the save method

```
[Error: Error updating a record.]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just combine `.findOne` and `.update`.

```
addFriend : function (req, res) {
    User.findOne({username : req.session.user.username}).exec(function (err, user) {
        var friends = user.friends ? user.friends : [];
        friends.push(req.param('friend'));
        User.update({username: req.session.user.username}, {friends: newFriends})
            .exec(function(err, updatedUser) {
                return res.json(updatedUser);
            });
    });
}
```